# How to estimate the upper bound of y?

Tags: estimation, bounds

How can you estimate the upper bound of $y$ in this situation? Given:

1. a function $y=f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ with 5 parameters ($y=f(\cdot,\cdot,\cdot,\cdot,\cdot)$ can be any function).
2. for each $x_i$ there are $k_i$ possible values.

I want to estimate the upper bound of $y$ but I don't want to try all combinations of input, which has size $k_1k_2k_3k_4k_5$.

Any idea or direction?

If that's not possible, are there any statistical methods to estimate the upper bound of $f$, given $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$, $x_5$?

Comment: A priori, I don't see any reason to suspect an upper bound even exists. Note that you haven't actually specified any concrete situation, you have a completely unspecified function of 5 unspecified variables. Are your x variables bounded at all? If the function turns over like an upside-down multidimensional parabola, it would be possible to find an upper bound. Upper bounds exist for some other functions, & also don't exist for many other functions. Without more information, I don't think anything can be said.

Comment: @gung It is implicit that the $k_i$ are finite, whence the domain of $f$ is finite, whence it attains its maximum.  Your objections nevertheless are valid: without any assumptions on $f$, the fact that it's a function is of no value: all we have is a population of $k_1k_2\ldots k_5$ values and the question asks how to estimate its maximum from a sample.  There are indeed statistical methods to do this but they are trivial: if you want to have, say, 95% confidence that the maximum has appeared in a random sample, then you have to sample 95% of the population!

Comment: In case that $f$ is given, can we use differentiation $f$ with respect to $x_1,x_2,...,x_5$ to find the optimal value of each $x_i$ and compare the optimal values with each $x_i$ respectively. Then, take each nearest $x_i$ (to the optimal $x_i$) as the estimated optimal value of $x_i$?